# Inequality involving expectation and summation of probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n)\leq E(|X|)\leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n).$$

--I have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(n\leq |X|<n+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nE(I_{\{n,n+1\}}|X|).$$ Thus since $n\leq X$, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(nI_{\{n,n+1\}}|X|)\leq E(|X|)$.

--I also say $E(|X|)=\int_{\Lambda_{n}}|X|\,dP=\int_{\Omega}|X|I_{\Lambda_{n}}\,dP$, where $\Lambda_{n}=\{n\leq |X|\leq n+1\}$.

--I am not sure if the above is completely right. Can I use similar reasoning to show that $E(|X|)\leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n)$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you explain how you get the second line ($$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(n\leq |X|<n+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nE(I_{\{n,n+1\}}|X|).$$)?

Comment: I don't believe that is correct, I am rather stuck. I am trying to use the result that, if $a\leq X\leq b$, then $aP(A)\leq\int_{A}X\,dP\leq bP(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Similar to your ideas: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}P(m\leq|X|< m+1)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}P(m\leq|X|< m+1)$$
$$ =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(m\leq|X|< m+1)  \leq \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\int I_{\{m\leq|X|< m+1 \}} |X|dP = \mathbb{E}\left[|X| \right] $$
$$ \leq \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)P(m\leq|X|< m+1) $$ $$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n) + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}P(m\leq|X|< m+1) $$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n) +1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the inequality

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} 1_{\{|X| \geq n\}} \leq |X| \leq 1+ \sum_{n \geq 1} 1_{\{|X| \geq n\}}$$

holds pointwise. Now take expectations.

Comment: Good idea... $ $