# A question about absolute moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question:

Let $c$ be any fixed positive constant. Show that if $E(|X|)<\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq cn)<\infty$.

--I am trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq cn)\leq E(|X|)$. My attempt at the solution:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq cn)&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}P(mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c)\\
   &=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mP(mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c)\\
   &=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}mE(1_{\{mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c\}})\\
   &=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}E(m1_{\{mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c\}})\\
   &\leq\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}E\left(|X|1_{\{mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c\}}\right)\\
   &=E\left(|X|\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}1_{\{mc\leq|X|<(m+1)c\}}\right)\\
   &=E(|X|)
\end{align*}

--My issue is that, if $mc\leq|X|$, then $m$ is not necessarily $\leq|X|$, since $c$ could be less than 1 (i.e., jumping from line 4 to 5). I think I am close, but how could I fix this so it works?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is an epidemic...

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq c \cdot n) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|)$$

you are trying to prove does in general **not** hold. Consider for example $X=1$, $c=0.5$, then

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|)=1$$

and

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq n/2) = 2.$$

---

**Hint** Use that $$\mathbb{E}(m 1_{\{mc \leq |X| \leq (m+1)c\}}) = \mathbb{E}(m 1_{\{m \leq |X|/c \leq (m+1)\}}) \leq \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{|X|}{c} 1_{\{mc \leq |X| \leq (m+1)c\}}\right).$$

---

**Remark** A much shorter proof is the following: Note that

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq cn) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X|/c \geq n).$$

for $c>0$. Applying the [well-known inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686348/)

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|Y| \geq n) \leq \mathbb{E}(|Y|)$$

finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So using this well-known equality, can we say that $\sum_{n\geq1}P(|X|/c\geq n)\leq E(|X|)/c\implies\sum_{n\geq1}P(|X|/c\geq n)\leq E(|X|)$? I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct here, since $c>0$ rather than $c>1$.

Comment: @KirkFogg No, this implication does not hold. You only have to prove $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq cn) < \infty$ and this follows directly from the first inequality: $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq cn) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X|/c \geq n) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|)}{c} < \infty$$